# How can I remove a class from jQuery UI Dialog?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

jQuery UI dialog has an option to add a class:

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-dialogClass

Is there any way I can remove specific class from the dialog?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the class option

```
// Get the existing class string
var dlgClass = $( ".selector" ).dialog("option", "dialogClass");

// remove the offending class
dlgClass.replace("delete-this-class", "");

// reset the dialog class
$(".selector").dialog("option", "dialogClass", dlgClass);
```

Or you can do a `split(" ")` or Regex to check for word breaks to modify the class value.

**Edit**

I've attempted to use `removeClass` but the widget appears to track classes you've added separately. This doesn't appear to work work:

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false, dialogClass: "foo bar" });
...
$("#dialog").closest(".ui-dialog").removeClass("foo");
var dialogClass = $("#dialog").dialog("option", "dialogClass");
console.log(dialogClass);  // foo bar
```

Regardless, I'd be reluctant to rely on the widget's DOM structure this way.